# Unable to install BIDS for SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, business-intelligence

I am working on a machine with Windows XP Service Pack 3. I have Visual Studio 2010 and have installed the express version of SQL Server 2008.

I got a SQL Server 2005 server for my development environment. I need to write a SSIS package.My machine doesn't have BIDS.

I tried installing BIDS with my SQL Server 2005 software and it is not going through the entire installation and it is failing.

I checked the Event Viewer and it has information - Event ID 1033 Source: MSiInstaller.

I don't have any other information (I know it is tough to troubleshoot installation issues with the information I have provided.) and wondering has anyone encountered this error?

Comment: Hard to tell, can you try enabling verbose logging for the installer? Locate the MSI file, then run the following command:
`msiexec /i [MSI file] /l*vx`

Comment: The correct syntax is `msiexec /i [MSI file] /l*vx setup.log`

Comment: Thanks Dan! I tried above comment and now I have got an error message stating - "The installer has encountered an unexpected error. The error code is 2356. Could not locate cabinet in stream: sql.cab"

Comment: It looks like the media or file is corrupted, and the recommendation is to download the installer again: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/c4c8408a-4210-40d0-bd15-83764a71037f. Sorry for not being able to help you more.